# Doubt on linear and circular convolution derivation

Tags: dft, convolution

[I'm very new to this website and to DSP in general as well! :)]

Hello everyone!

I have a question on the derivation of the circular convolution.
As far as I understand, we can define a circular convolution between two finite length signals g and h in the following way:

[source of all images: [Convolution theorem - Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Functions_of_a_discrete_variable_(sequences))

[image]

The thing that I struggle with is the second part of the definition:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the direction of a proof for the above relation? Is it just a definition that I can give for granted or is there something more about it?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

So far I've tried with the following reasoning:

Suppose $x[n]$ and $y[n]$ are two finite-length signals of length $N$.
Starting from:

$$x_N\ast y = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}{x_N[m]y[n-m]} = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}{x_N[n-m]y[m]}$$

given the fact that $y[n]$ is a finite-length signal:

$$\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}{x_N[n-m]y[m]}=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}{x_N[n-m]y[m]}=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}{x_N[n-m]y_N[m]}$$

Seems legit so far; can this be acceptable?